# Combinatorics Statistics Probability of a Letter Chain

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains

What formula could help me quantify the probability of a chain of three letters (English Alphabet) where each letter is based on the previous one (stochastic modeling, Markov-chains, probabilities)

Example with the word "Bake" 
What is the probability of AKE, where A depends on B, K depends on A, and E depends on K.

Example with the word "State"
What is the probability of ATE where A depends on T, T depends on A and E depends on T.

As the letters are not equiprobable as they depend on the previous one (as shown in the example).

Comment: Not sure if I understood you properly.
You can have any of 26 letters on one of those places. So 3 letters word can be constructed in 26^3 ways. You want to choose one option so 1/(26^3) is probability of each combination.

Comment: Yes of course, that's fine with me although, that's only right when the letters are equiprobable, which is not the case, as for the english dictionary you will never have  WWW as a word ending, so I'm looking into stochastic models, markov chain (something like that)

Answer (score 0):

Not much of a formula; really just an expression that encodes the rules you've described in your question:

Let $\alpha$ represent the start of the word, and $\omega$ represent the end of the word.  Let $\Sigma = \{A, B, \ldots, Z, \alpha, \omega\}$ be the alphabet.  Then we denote the letter-transition probabilities by $p_{\mu,\nu} \equiv P(\beta_{i+1} = \nu \mid \beta_i = \mu)$ for any $i$, where $\mu, \nu \in \Sigma$.  Any given word $\beta_1\beta_2\cdots\beta_n$ then has the probability

$$
P = p_{\alpha,\beta_1} p_{\beta_n,\omega}
    \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} p_{\beta_i, \beta_{i+1}}
$$

In general, there's no short cut.  If the letters are independent, then we can replace $p_{\mu,\nu}$ by $p_{\nu}$, but otherwise, there's no additional short cut there, either.